# UIViewController freezes after making a network request while Google Maps is navigating

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiviewcontroller

We have an elusive issue which is sporadically reproducible where a UIViewController stops responding to touches. It only seems to occur after sending a network request through a presented view controller *while* Google Maps navigation is running in the background.

Here's how it is (sometimes) reproduced:

1. Start navigation in Google Maps
2. Switch back to our app
3. Make a network request in a presented view controller
4. Dismiss the presented view controller

After that, the presenting view controller is unresponsive to touches.

Does anyone have any insight into what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Check network request whether on main thread or check if a modal window cover you view.

If main thread is still run, responsibility chain may not deliver UIEvent correctly.